# Create View with Two columns in Two Tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

There are two tables: `sales` and `expenses`. `sales` has two columns: `sale_date` and `price`, expenses table has two columns: `date` and `amount`. also have a `view` with days in 
year. ([Create View with 365 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531269/create-view-with-365-days))

i want to add another two columns to this view: `sales` and `expenses` with data in `sales` and 
`expenses` tables.

example :

`Sales` `Table`

```
sale_date   price

05-DEC-11   1,500
05-DEC-11     500
11-DEC-11     800
17-DEC-11   2,400
```

`Expenses` `Table`

```
date        amount

06-DEC-11      300
11-DEC-11      100
11-DEC-11      400
15-DEC-11    1,100
```

`View` should create as below

```
date        sales   expenses

01-JAN-11    null    null
02-JAN-11    null    null
03-JAN-11    null    null
04-JAN-11    null    null
05-JAN-11    null    null

...


05-DEC-11   2,000    null
06-DEC-11    null     300
07-DEC-11    null    null
08-DEC-11    null    null
09-DEC-11    null    null
10-DEC-11    null    null
11-DEC-11     800     500
12-DEC-11    null    null
13-DEC-11    null    null
14-DEC-11    null    null
15-DEC-11    null   1,100
16-DEC-11    null    null
17-DEC-11   2,400    null

...


28-DEC-11   null     null
29-DEC-11   null     null
30-DEC-11   null     null
31-DEC-11   null     null
```

`sales` and `expenses` columns in view created with sum of `price` and `amount` Columns in `sale` and `expenses` table group by `date` in those two tables.

how could i do this ?

Comment: I'm not sure but did you try to create that view on your own before you posted here?

Comment: @Lion i tried to do that. but unable to fill view with sum of columns group by date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you there:

```
SELECT the_day, price, amount
  FROM year_days LEFT JOIN (SELECT sale_date, SUM(price) price
                              FROM sales
                             GROUP BY sale_date) ON the_day = sale_date
                 LEFT JOIN (SELECT expense_date, SUM(expenses) amount
                              FROM expenses
                             GROUP BY expense_date) ON the_day = expense_date
 ORDER BY the_day;

THE_DAY        PRICE     AMOUNT
--------- ---------- ----------
...
01-DEC-11
02-DEC-11
03-DEC-11
04-DEC-11
05-DEC-11       2000
06-DEC-11                   300
07-DEC-11
08-DEC-11
09-DEC-11
10-DEC-11
11-DEC-11        800        500
12-DEC-11
13-DEC-11
14-DEC-11
15-DEC-11                  1100
16-DEC-11
17-DEC-11       2400
18-DEC-11
...
```

Comment: How can i write above query with query in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531269/create-view-with-365-days] as a one query ?